# Errors when trying to build the game "The Secret Chronicles of Dr. M" with cmake

Tags: software-installation, compiling, games, cmake

When I run the command  `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/tsc`  to install the game from source the terminal gives:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/tsc
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:90 (file):
  file Internal CMake error when trying to open file:
  /home//TSC/tsc/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
  for writing.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:100 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_WRITE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:39 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:127 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (enable_language)


CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:90 (file):
  file Internal CMake error when trying to open file:
  /home//TSC/tsc/CMakeFiles/2.8.12.2/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
  for writing.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:100 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_WRITE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:39 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:127 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (enable_language)


-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
CMake Error: your CXX compiler: "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND" was not found.   Please set CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to a valid compiler path or name.
```

What is wrong here? How can I fix it? I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the required build compilers and libraries:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install build-essential
```